# Class libraries are out of sync warnings from Mono

Tags: c#, linux, mono

We built on mono 5.20.1.19 from GitHub. We have many com interop projects, which work well in Mono 4.8 on Linux. However in 5.20, we see lots of warnings as follows:

> Your mono runtime and class libraries are out of sync.
>   The out of sync library is: Foo.dll

When you update one from git you will also need to update, compile and install the other too. Do not report this as a bug unless you're sure you have updated correctly: you probably have a broken mono install.
If you see other errors or faults after this message they are probably related and you need to fix your mono install first.
cant resolve internal call to "Bar::.ctor" (tested without signature also)

Most com interop projects are still functional, but those warnings look scary. Every project is build from scratch, what is the reason for all those warning?

Comment: this question is lacking so many details; how did you build and instal mono 5.20? what version of Linux are you using?

Comment: @knocte Sorry for the late response. I was on vacation in the last couple of weeks. The  instruction I followed to build Mono from a git source code checkout is here: 
https://www.mono-project.com/docs/compiling-mono/linux/
The linux versions I have tried are Red Hat 6.9 and SUSE 12.4.